# A duplication in URL route Laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I m trying to acces the create page from the navbar when i m under the home page i can access to the url without problem ('http://todolist.test/todo/create') but when i try to acces from the show page the url have a duplication ('http://todolist.test/todo/todo/create')
"todo" repeated 2 times in url .

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="{{Request::is('/')? 'active' : ''}}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="{{Request::is('todo/create')? 'active' : ''}}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="todo/create">Create Todo</a>
          </li>


        </ul>
```

**create page route**
Method :GET|HEAD  | URI :todo/create      | Name :todo.create  | Action: App\Http\Controllers\TodosController@create  |Middleware: web 
 **show page route**
Method:GET|HEAD  | URI:todo/{todo}      | Name:todo.show    |Action: App\Http\Controllers\TodosController@show    |  Middleware:web

Comment: This is a common problem with relative urls(like `href="todo/create"`) The way that I solve it is by using the `asset()` function like so: `href="{{ asset('todo/create') }}"`(assuming you are in a blade file)

Comment: You can also defile it for js like so: `<script>function asset(url) { return '{{ asset('') }}' + url; }</script>` inside a blade file

Comment: @RobBiermann thanks a lot sir it worked you are my saver but if possible can you explain me why it worked with assets and not direct link cause i want to understant things not just running code. sry for my bad english and thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A link reference like `href="todo/create"` adds these words to your current url(in address bar), if the page you are on is http://yourdomain.com/ , it refers to http://yourdomain.com/todo/create

If you are then using the same code to create the link, and you click it again( assuming it is in your header or statically implemented on the page) it will direct to http://yourdomain.com/todo/create/todo/create

Therefor i strongly advice to take the dynamic approch with using a function to 'generate' your url( based on your host settings).

`asset('your/extension/goes/here')` is a function supplied by laravel, and it does just that: generate your base_url.

If the `href="todo/create"` receives a url starting with a protocol(like `http` and `https`, it wil not add the string to the url, but call it directly.

So using `href="{{ asset('todo/create') }}"` will render into `href="http://yourdomain.com/todo/create"` in every situation, thereby fixing your issue :).

Comment: thanks so much dear sir hope you have a nice day you are my hero

Answer (score 3):

I would just add a leading / to your url:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/todo/create">Create Todo</a>
```